# I want to remove category (edit/delete) buttons from wordpress dashboard

Tags: php, wordpress

If didn't get what I mean, here is the details:

In wordpress dashboard (wp-admin) in category section, if you hover over a category there's some buttons appears down the category.

these buttons are (edit, quick edit and delete)

Simply, I want my users to add categories but I don't want them to edit or delete categories.

So, I want to get rid of these buttons (removing these buttons).

I have searched in wordpress files but couldn't find anything :(

Any help guys?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the CSS technique for this issue is not the best approach. Since WordPress v3.0.0 a new filter hook is available to filter them using PHP:

```
<?php
add_action( 'my_taxonomy_row_actions', 'wpse31545522_restrict_edit_delete_in_category', 10, 2 );

function wpse31545522_restrict_edit_delete_in_category($actions, $tag) {
    unset($actions['edit']); // Edit link
    unset($actions['inline hide-if-no-js']); //Inline Edit link
    unset($actions['delete']); // Delete link

    return $actions;
}
```

If you want to impose restriction only on certain terms, you can embrace the `unset()` declarations inside a conditional:

```
<?php
function wpse31545522_restrict_edit_delete_in_category($actions, $tag) {
    if( in_array($tag->slug, array('news', 'notice')) ) {
        unset($actions['edit']); // Edit link
        unset($actions['inline hide-if-no-js']); //Inline Edit link
        unset($actions['delete']); // Delete link
    }

    return $actions;
}
```

### Documentaion

- [Filter Hook: `{$taxonomy}_row_actions`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/taxonomy_row_actions/) - WordPress Developer Resource

Answer (score 0):

You could use CSS to hide those links from appearing on hover. The following code adds custom styles to the admin area.

```
add_action('admin_head', 'hide_category_buttons');

function hide_category_buttons() {
  echo '<style>
    .taxonomy-category tr:hover .row-actions {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
  </style>';
}
```

Comment: Its works! thank you man! you solved my problem and I have learned a new function :)

Comment: I'm glad you found it useful.!

Comment: I have discovered something dangerous! when you use a developer tool in chrome you can edit the css classes and html codes. So simply you can edit the visibility to show the element. What if someone used this to edit the visibility and remove all categories!! it's dangerous. Becuase this I want to remove these buttons from its source

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery to achieve the same. 
Just write your custom code in a js file which is called on that page so that it contains code to hide the 3 links displayed for each category or enqueue a JS file with your custom code to this category dashboard page.

This will definitely work for you.